# laravel queue daemon mail stops functioning with SSL error

Tags: php, email, ssl, laravel, laravel-4

I am running a laravel queue daemon, which sends mail depending on the actions taken. This is running through supervisor to ensure it always runs. It works fine at first, but after some time the mail stops sending. The error is not reporting up the chain, but the logs show:

```
[2014-07-30 20:00:21] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry' in /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:232
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'fwrite(): SSL o...', '/srv/www/example...', 232, Array)
#1 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(232): fwrite(Resource id #376, 'MAIL FROM: <hel...')
#2 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/AbstractFilterableInputStream.php(171): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_commit('MAIL FROM: <hel...')
#3 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/AbstractFilterableInputStream.php(90): Swift_ByteStream_AbstractFilterableInputStream->_doWrite('MAIL FROM: <hel...')
#4 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(274): Swift_ByteStream_AbstractFilterableInputStream->write('MAIL FROM: <hel...')
#5 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(243): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM: <hel...', Array, Array)
#6 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(323): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM: <hel...', Array)
#7 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(416): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doMailFromCommand('hello@example.co...')
#8 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(444): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_doMailTransaction(Object(Swift_Message), 'hello@example.co...', Array, Array)
#9 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(174): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_sendTo(Object(Swift_Message), 'hello@example.co...', Array, Array)
#10 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(85): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#11 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(328): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#12 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(150): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
#13 /srv/www/example.co.uk/bootstrap/compiled.php(3231): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send('emails.campaign...', Array, Object(Closure))
#14 /srv/www/example.co.uk/app/commands/Sender.php(252): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('send', Array)
#15 /srv/www/example.co.uk/app/commands/Sender.php(252): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('emails.campaign...', Array, Object(Closure))
#16 /srv/www/example.co.uk/app/commands/Sender.php(116): Sender->_sendEmail(Array, Array, Array, Array)
#17 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(96): Sender->queue(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Array)
#18 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/RedisJob.php(46): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->resolveAndFire(Array)
#19 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(192): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob->fire()
#20 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(142): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), '2', 0)
#21 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(101): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->pop('redis', NULL, 0, '3', '2')
#22 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(73): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runNextJobForDaemon('redis', NULL, 0, '3', '2')
#23 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(98): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('redis', NULL, 0, 128, '3', '2')
#24 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(68): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('redis', NULL, 0, 128, true)
#25 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(112): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
#26 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(100): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(887): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#29 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(193): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#30 /srv/www/example.co.uk/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#31 /srv/www/example.co.uk/artisan(59): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#32 {main} [] []
```

I'm suck for ideas? I'm using sendgrid for mailing

edit, Same as here: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/490

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Not sure what is more programming that a stack trace of a programming error, but ok

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug inside Laravel/Swift and the way that it is handling it's sockets inside the long running queue worker. The best way to avoid this issue is to make sure that you are closing your transport after each email has been sent.

There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4573) inside Laravel's bug tracker that has a couple of patches to the Laravel code base that will resolve this issue.

Alternatively, have a look at the [YOzaz/Laravel-SwiftMailer](https://github.com/YOzaz/Laravel-SwiftMailer) package, which has an updated Mail facade that will most likely resolve the problem that you are having.