# Certificate issue with SOAP

Tags: php, ssl, soap, openssl

I am using `SoapClient` to communicate with the server that requires a digitally signed requests only and everything was OK until yesterday.
I have asked the provider did they made any changes and they told me they haven't. I haven't made any changes at all and it just started showing me this error:

```
 "SoapClient::__doRequest(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure"
```

The provider doesn't lock by IP.

Can someone provide me some information about this error because everything I have already googled didn't helped me at all....

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: what did you google'd already? so we don't waste time looking through the same issues twice

Comment: everything that is showing when i type the error, but there isn't anything about  that specific number of the error "140940E5"...

Comment: you sure? because i just googled and within 30 secs i found this SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32021556/4207875)

Comment: that is not the same error .... and I dont use cURL

Comment: it is the very same error number, and its not about using curl, its about setting up the certificate correctly

Comment: Thank you for your time but that is not helping me, my server is Linux based and everything was working fine until yesterday.... I have checked my certificate, it expires in 2018 so it's not that... do u have any other suggestions where the problem might comes from ?

FYI: it was properly working on my localhost also and now i get the same mistake there .....

Comment: I noticed it being a SSL3 Handshake. Maybe a security update on the server introduced removal of SSL3 as legit means of cipher?

Comment: How can i check the versions of SSL ?